# Making a Siyum on Purim

Tags: halacha, purim

Can you make a siyum on Purim by the seudah? I know there is a concept of not mixing simchas but was wondering if a siyum falls into that category.

Comment: Purim should be no worse than Yom Tov in this regard, and we make a siyum every year on the last Yom Tov of Sukkot

Comment: The MA brings up your question about weddings on Purim: [שולחן ערוך אורח חיים תרצו ח](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95_%D7%97)

Comment: All I know is that my family holds, yes. We do one every year actually